# did not find expected key error when trying to limit memory

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run a test container through the Kubernetes but I got error. The below is my `deploy.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
      requests:
          storage: 2Gi
          cpu: 0.5
          memory: "128M"
      limits:
          cpu: 0.5
          memory: "128M" # This is the line throws error
          - type: PersistentVolumeClaim
          max:
            storage: 2Gi
          min:
            storage: 1Gi
.
.
.
```

When I run `kubectl apply -k .`, I get this error:

```
error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from 'deploy.yaml': yaml: line 19: did not find expected key': got file 'deploy.yaml', but '/home/kus/deploy.yaml' must be a directory to be a root
```

I tried to read the [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) but I cannot understand why I'm getting error.

**Edit 1**

I changed my `deploy.yaml` file as @whites11 said, now it's like:

```
.
.
.
spec:
  limits:
    memory: "128Mi"
    cpu: 0.5
.
.
.
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
resourcequota/storagequota unchanged
service/nginx configured
error: error validating ".": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "limits" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: check your yaml syntax again

Comment: @Jonas I edited my question, so would you please check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you shared is not valid YAML.

```
limits:
     cpu: 0.5
     memory: "128M" # This is the line throws error
     - type: PersistentVolumeClaim
     max:
       storage: 2Gi
     min:
       storage: 1Gi
```

The `limits` field has mixed type (hash and collection) and is obviously wrong.

Seems like you took the syntax for specifying [pods resource limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) and mixed it with the one used to [limit storage consuption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/limit-storage-consumption/#limitrange-to-limit-requests-for-storage).

In your Deployment spec you might want to set limits simply like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - ...
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: "128M"
```

And deal with storage limits at the namespace level as described in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/limit-storage-consumption/#limitrange-to-limit-requests-for-storage).

Comment: I really cannot understand what's wrong with it unfortunately:( what key should it have? I studied a lot to figure it out but no luck:(

Comment: The only fields you should leave are "cpu" and "memory"

Comment: as per docs, it's like `spec.containers[].resources.limits.`, so I thought I should do like this. I edited the question and edit 1 is the new error. Do you mean I should use `limits` with no any indentations? Or it should be under `spec` with indentation?

Comment: Hi @Saeed, try to change deploy.yaml instead of kustomization.yaml.

Comment: Oops, `kustomization.yaml` has nothing but the names of the files, in fact I edited `deploy.yaml`, and that was a typo in edit. I edited it again.

Comment: The position was ok, take a look at the complete example I put in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `yaml` file to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```